# update if combination of 2 columns does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have 2 tables.

### group_owner

```
group_id  |   user_id
--------- | ----------
  51      |     1
  51      |     2
  51      |     3
  52      |     2
  53      |     4
```

### users

```
user_id   |   username
--------- | -----------
   1      |    John
   2      |    John
   3      |    John
   4      |    Peter
```

`user_id` of `group_owner` has foreign key relation with `user_id` of `users`.

I am removing duplicates from users table. I need to keep the user with lowest id if there are duplicates and delete rest of them. I created a temporary table as shown below.

```
SELECT
  t2.id    AS Old_id,
  t1.MinID AS New_id
INTO #Translation
FROM (SELECT
        MIN(id) AS MinID,
        username
      FROM users
      GROUP BY username) t1
  INNER JOIN users t2
    ON t1.username = t2.username
```

I need to replace `Old_ids` with `New_ids` in `group_owner` table. `group_owner` has constraint on `group_id` and `user_id`.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[group_owner] ADD  CONSTRAINT [pk_group_owner] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [group_id] ASC,
    [user_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

If that combination already exists it will blow up. So, doing the following will not work.

```
UPDATE group_owner 
  SET group_owner.[user_id] = New_id
  FROM group_owner 
    INNER JOIN #Translation T
      ON group_owner.[user_id] = T.Old_id
  WHERE T.Old_id <> T.New_id
```

Can someone help me in updating group_owner if that combination does not exists and deleting the combination if that combination exists?

Following is the group_owner and users tables should look like after processing:

### group_owner

```
group_id  |   user_id
--------- | ----------
  51      |     1
  52      |     1
  53      |     4
```

### users

```
user_id   |   username
--------- | -----------
   1      |    John
   4      |    Peter
```

Reference: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/10/07/2190.aspx

Comment: Edit your question and show what you want your tables to look like after you have completed the processing.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. I updated the question.

Comment: Can you please add sample data where you need to update Group_Owner data instead of delete/insert.

Comment: @Nasir I added sample data. group_id 52 points to user_id 2. But when duplicates are deleted, group_id 52 should point to user_id 1 because we are deleting users 2,3 as they are duplicates and 1 will remain because it has lowest id among duplicates with name John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below steps.

1. Deleting the unwanted records from the group_owner table.

   As you said group_id and user_id combination is unique we need only one entry for group_id =51 and user_id =1 ,so we can remove (51,2) and (51,3) combinations from group_owner .

Script  :

```
;with cte_1
    as
    (SELECT Username,[user_id],COUNT([user_id])OVER(PARTITION BY Username Order by [Username]) as CNT
    FROM users  )
    ,cte_2
    as
    (SELECT Username,a.[user_id],b.group_id  , ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY b.group_id Order by [user_id]) as Rno
    FROM cte_1 a
    JOIN group_owner b on a.[user_id]=b.[user_id]
    WHERE CNT>1)
    DELETE c3
    FROM cte_2 c2
      JOIN group_owner c3 on c2.group_id=c3.group_id and c2.[user_id]=c3.[user_id]
    WHERE Rno>1
```

2. Next step is to update the [user_id] in the group_owner table  with the Minimum user_id from user table.

Script:

```
;with cte_1
as
(SELECT Username,[user_id]
 ,COUNT([user_id])OVER(PARTITION BY Username Order by [Username]) as CNT
 ,MIN([user_id])OVER(PARTITION BY Username Order by [user_id]) as [MINUserID]
FROM users  )
UPDATE b
  SET b.user_id=a.[MINUserID]
FROM cte_1 a
 JOIN group_owner b on a.[user_id]=b.[user_id]
 WHERE CNT>1
```

3. Third and final step is to remove the duplicate entries from the User table by keeping minimum value of user id.

Script :

```
;with cte_1
    as
    (SELECT Username,[user_id],ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Username Order by [user_id]) as RNO
    FROM users  )
    DELETE 
    FROM cte_1
    WHERE RNO>1
```